# Correction in Regex for unicode

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need help for regex. My regex is not producing the desired results. Below is my code:

```
import re
text='<u+0001f48e> repairs <u+0001f6e0><u+fe0f>your loved<u+2764><u+fe0f>one 
on the spot<u+26a1>'
regex=re.compile(r'[<u+\w+]+>')
txt=regex.findall(text)
print(txt)
```

Output

```
['<u+0001f48e>', '<u+0001f6e0>', '<u+fe0f>', 'loved<u+2764>', '<u+fe0f>', 'spot<u+26a1>']
```

I know, regex is not correct. I want output as:

```
 '<u+0001f48e>', '<u+0001f6e0><u+fe0f>', '<u+2764><u+fe0f>', '<u+26a1>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'<u\+[0-9a-f]+>')
text = '<u+0001f48e> repairs <u+0001f6e0><u+fe0f>your loved<u+2764><u+fe0f>one on the spot<u+26a1>'

print(regex.findall(text))

# output:
['<u+0001f48e>', '<u+0001f6e0>', '<u+fe0f>', '<u+2764>', '<u+fe0f>', '<u+26a1>']
```

That is not exactly what you want, but its almost there.

Now, to achieve what you are looking for, we make our regex more eager:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'((?:<u\+[0-9a-f]+>)+)')
text = '<u+0001f48e> repairs <u+0001f6e0><u+fe0f>your loved<u+2764><u+fe0f>one on the spot<u+26a1>'

print(regex.findall(text))

# output:
['<u+0001f48e>', '<u+0001f6e0><u+fe0f>', '<u+2764><u+fe0f>', '<u+26a1>']
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want 2 and 3 elements as a pair. Similarly for 4th and 5th

Comment: Thanks dopstar. You seem to have solved my query. I tried a few examples and your regex is working as desired. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1992989: if it solves your problem you should accept the answer of dopstar.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you add optional 2nd tag search:

```
regex=re.compile(r'<([u+\w+]+>(<u+fe0f>)?)')
```

This one [works fine](https://pythex.org/?regex=%3C(%5Bu%2B%5Cw%2B%5D%2B%3E(%3Cu%2Bfe0f%3E)%3F)&test_string=%3Cu%2B0001f48e%3E%20repairs%20%3Cu%2B0001f6e0%3E%3Cu%2Bfe0f%3Eyour%20loved%3Cu%2B2764%3E%3Cu%2Bfe0f%3Eone%20%0Aon%20the%20spot%3Cu%2B26a1%3E&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) with your example.

Comment: Thanks. <u+fe0f> is not fixed in other examples

Comment: So please provide the ones that it is failing for.